# Nginx proxy truncating GET requests at & character

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We're using Nginx as a reverse proxy. When a request containing the & character passes through the proxy, it gets truncated at that point. Here's an HTTP request header from the packet capture to show what's happening:

```
16:55:01.358854 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29879, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 223)
    226166-5.50452 > 192.168.0.3.http: Flags [P.], cksum 0x168e (incorrect -> 0xea18), seq 1:172, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 317402706 ecr 653213440], length 171: HTTP, length: 171
    GET /UploadService/UploadService.svc/GetFile?associateId=f84c53b6-823d-4e52-aca4-d7e268a61712 HTTP/1.1
    Host: cfmapi.ourdomain.com
    User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
    Accept: */*
```

The full URL in the proxied GET request should be:

```
/UploadService/UploadService.svc/GetFile?associateId=f84c53b6-823d-4e52-aca4-d7e268a61712&filename=c92aed2a-d859-4050-9e6b-8a60428b720e.pdf
```

The proxy section in our Nginx config is:

```
location /cfmapi/ {
    proxy_pass http://cfmapi.ourdomain.com/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
    proxy_redirect default;
    } #End location
```

(Domain names changed purposely.)

Any idea what's causing this truncation and how to stop it?

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.14.2
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-compat --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-u35_og/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-u35_og/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-dav-ext --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-u35_og/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-u35_og/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-u35_og/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-subs-filter
```

Comment: What is `226166-5`? What is `192.168.0.3`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't realize some confusing things were in the packet capture.

`226166-5` is the host name, and `192.168.0.3` is the destination server being proxied to.

Comment: Where is the packet capture of the request that nginx received?